# Verificar usuario logeado con extensiones chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Tengo una extension para google chrome pero quiero que esta verifique si el usuario está logeado correctamente en la página principal.

¿Como puedo realizar esta verificación desde la extensión?

Un ejemplo claro es la extensión de trello, verifica que tu cuenta esté logeada.

[Link para instalar la extensión de trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boards-for-trello/eknhddnoflchkcccjgdddmnimjggiona/related?hl=es-419)

Comment: qué significa que el usuario esté logueado? cómo verificas eso en la página principal? se verifica en el backend?

Comment: O se, para que se habilite la extensión el usuario debe estar logeado en la sistema

Comment: Ok, pero si la extensión no existiera, qué características te permiten identificar que el usuario está logueado? Hay una respuesta del backend que un usuario logueado vería y otros no?

Comment: Así es, si un usuario no está logeado muestra otras cosas y si lo está muestra otro contenido.

Comment: Entonces debieras hacer que tu extensión enviara un request a tu página, y parseando la respuesta dedujera si ya estás logueado.

Answer (score 0):

Trata de utilizar datos en el cache para verificar q el usuario ya esta dentro o ya esta logeado.

puedes utilizar el local storage 
ya hay un js que hace todo el trabajo.

http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/

con esto puedes mantener datos en tu navegador siempre y cuando no se limpie el cache del historial de navegacion

implementacion

```
 //set Cookie
amplify.storage("myvar",'{"id":"1234","nombre":"jose","session":true}');

//get Cookie
 amplify.storage("myvar");
```

y puedes hacer una validacion para ver si esta logeado

```
if(amplify.storage("myvar") != undefined){

entrar_main();

}else{

ir_loggin();

}
```

Comment: no se si me explique

Comment: No entendí muy bien, me podrías ayudar en privado?

Comment: esta bien nada mas por donde me podria comunicar contigo